# Build in Jenkins using GIT

Tags: git, plugins, jenkins

I tried to create a job for the build for the code in the remote master of the GIT repository. But we are interested in building from other branch in GIT. Will the branch specifier be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I have been using the 'Branch specifier' for a while and it works as expected.
[image: Branch specifier]

Answer (score 1):

Yes - Specifying the branch on the job will track and build from that branch.

From Jenkins GIT plugin:

> Specify the branches if you'd like to track a specific branch in a repository. If left blank, all branches will be examined for changes and built.
>
> The syntax is of the form: REPOSITORYNAME/BRANCH. In addition, BRANCH is recognized as a shorthand of */BRANCH, '*' is recognized as a wildcard, and '**' is recognized as wildcard that includes the separator '/'. Therefore, origin/branches* would match origin/branches-foo but not origin/branches/foo, while origin/branches** would match both origin/branches-foo and origin/branches/foo.
>
> If you are using namespaces to structure branches (e.g. feature1/master, or team1/requestA/rel-1.0) you have to specify the full branch specifier (including "remotes/"): remotes/REPOSITORYNAME/BRANCH/WITH/NAMESPACE.
> E.g. "remotes/origin/feature1/master"
> A specific revision can be checked out by specifying the SHA1 hash of that revision in this field.